# Change app language at run time

Tags: ios, swift3, nslocalizedstring

I am trying to change the the lang that I get with NSLocalizedString at run time.

I know that this question as been already asking, but I do not find an answers for Swift 3.

I have try:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
UserDefaults.standard.set("en", forKey: "AppleLanguages")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

and:

```
let language = "en"
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj")
let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
let string = bundle?.localizedString(forKey: "AppleLanguages", value: language, table: nil)
```

but nothing works....

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the end, I've used a custom localisator class available on Github, which allow you to switch language from anywhere in the app and even save if for further launches of the app.

It is written in swift 2.2, but Xcode automatically update the code to Swift 3. Just had to change at to places in the Demo:

```
notification.name == kNotificationLanguageChanged
```

to:

```
notification.name.rawValue == kNotificationLanguageChanged
```

https://github.com/micazeve/iOS-CustomLocalisator